# How can a UITableViewCell know what JSON to load from an Array or Dictionaries

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview, dictionary

Let's say I have an array of 3 dictionaries in JSON and each of those has it's own type (demo, entry, comment).

```
[
{
    "_id": "random ID",
    "profile": "random ID Profile",
    "demo": {
        "_id": "random ID",
        "profile": {
            "_id": "random ID",
            "name": "name",
            "username": "username",
            "description": "description",
            "picture": "/picture"
        },
        "path": "/path",
        "created": "date"
    },
    "type": "demo",
    "source": "570aa8f647a70780a7111e91",
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "date"
},
{
    "_id": "random ID",
    "comment": "random comment ID",
    "type": "comment",
    "source": "57077c4e356c10371ca91ad9",
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "date"
},
{
    "_id": "random ID",
    "entry": "random entry ID",
    "type": "entry",
    "source": "57077c4e356c10371ca91ad9",
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "date"
}
]
```

Right now I'm checking the type in the request so I only get the demo.

```
    func getTimeline(urlString: NSURL, completion: ([ModelDemos]) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString).responseJSON { response in

        if let httpResponse = response.response {
            switch httpResponse.statusCode {
            case 200:
                var modelTimeline = [ModelDemos]()

                if let demos = response.result.value as? [JSONDictionary] {
                    for demo in demos {
                        if let type = demo["type"] as? String {
                            if type == "demo" {
                                if let demo = demo["demo"] as? JSONDictionary {
                                    let JSON = ModelDemos(data: demo)
                                    modelTimeline.append(JSON)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else { print("not working") }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    completion(modelTimeline)
                    print("Am I back on the main thread ? Response: \(NSThread.isMainThread())")
                }
            default:
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this setting a completion method in my TimelineViewController

```
var timelineDemos = [ModelDemos]()

func runApiManagerTimeline() {
    guard let urlString = urlString else {return}
    apiManagerCurrentUserProfile.getTimeline(urlString, completion: didGetCurrentUserProfileDemos)
}

func didGetCurrentUserProfileDemos(demos: [ModelDemos]) {
    timelineDemos = demos
    timelineCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

All works fine, I get only the demo Dictionary and I can load it to the DemoUITableViewCell.

Now I have to create 3 different types of UITableViewCell for each of the Dictionary from the array. Imagine it as a Facebook feed where each Dictionary is different and the number is continuously growing.

How would I tell each Cell what content it should load?

Comment: Your question isnt clear at the end, please explain in your question what do you mean exactly for "tell each Cell what content it should load". How many cell you want to have? 1 per dictionary?

Comment: It's like the notifications tab on the Facebook or Instagram app, there could be unlimited number of dictionaries (cells), but each cell has it's own information and ordered by the date each notification was made.

Comment: If a dictionary is a type of Demo I want to load that information in DemoUItableViewCell, if a dictionary is of type Entry i want to load that information in EntryUItableViewCell, and so on... But in the order that was given to me by the JSON response.

Comment: Always hard to understand but I've try to give  an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another good example to use a custom struct as model for the data source array.

First create an `enum` to map the `String` types to `enum` cases

```
enum DataType : String { case Demo = "demo", Comment = "comment", Entry = "entry" }
```

Create a custom `struct` item as data source model. Declare all common properties of the three data types **without** an initial value, individual properties **with** a initial value to use the implicit memberwise initializer to create the `Item` instance and assign values to the individual properties depending on the type. The sample properties are from the JSON and only an example

```
struct Item {
  // common properties
  var type : DataType
  var source : String
  var created : String

  // individual properties
  var username = ""
  var description = ""
  var picture = ""
}
```

In the TableView controller create the data source array

```
var modelTimeline = [Item]()
```

and create `Item` instances while parsing the JSON

```
...
if let demos = response.result.value as? [JSONDictionary] {
  for demo in demos {
    if let type = demo["type"] as? String {
      let source = type["source"] ?? ""
      let created = type["date"] ?? ""
      var item = Item(type: DataType(rawValue:type), source: source, created: created)
      if type == "demo" {
        if let demo = demo["demo"] as? JSONDictionary, profile = demo["profile"] as? JSONDictionary {
          item.username = profile["username"] ?? ""
          item.description = profile["description"] ?? ""
          item.picture = profile["picture"] ?? ""
        }
      }
      modelTimeline.append(item)
    }
  }
} else { print("not working") }
...
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` create cells and assign values to the UI elements depending on the type

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let item = modelTimeline[indexPath.row]
  switch item.type {
    case .Demo:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DemoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DemoUItableViewCell
    cell.usernameLabel.text = item.username
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = item.description
    cell.sourceLabel.text = item.source
    // populate other UI elements
    return cell

    case .Comment:
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! CommentUItableViewCell
    cell.sourceLabel.text = item.source
    // populate other UI elements
    return cell

    case .Entry:
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EntryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! EntryUItableViewCell
    cell.sourceLabel.text = item.source
    // populate other UI elements
    return cell
  }
}
```

The code is not a full working version, it's just a suggestion how to use different cells for different types.

Comment: This worked out best as a framework to build upon, thank you very much ! I will update with how it looks after a full implementation.

Comment: I like your code but Im not agree with "declaration without an initial value", if your datas can handle by NSCoder you can have some problems..

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano As mentioned, it's a suggestion. But *declaration without an initial value* means only that using the required memberwise initializer will initialize all values of the common variables reliably since they are non-optionals.

Answer (score 0):

With those methods:

```
    // MARK: - Table view Functions
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //3 because of 3 different dictionaries
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//Define the amount of rows for each section
    if (section == 0) {
        return --amount of entries in regarding dictionary--
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return --amount of entries in regarding dictionary--
    } else {
        return --amount of entries in regarding dictionary--
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 if (indexPath.section == 0) {
      //Dict 1
 } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
      //Dict 2
 } else {
      //Dict 3
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this would work well when you know the exact number of responses and where each of those responses have to be in the section. Imagine my example as a Facebook feed where each post is different and  you need to determine what the Cell needs to load.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to customize your datasource making a class (internal class or not) like:

```
class GeneralNotificationInfo: NSObject {
    var notificationTime:NSDate! = NSDate()
    enum notificationType: Int {
        case Demo = 1
        case Entry = 2
        case Test = 3
    }
    var data:NSDictionary! = NSDictionary()
    ...
}
```

With this personalization you can easily handle your cell.

About your code:

```
typealias AlamoNetSuccess = (result: NSDictionary?) -> Void
typealias AlamoNetProgress = (result: NSDictionary?) -> Void
typealias AlamoNetFailure = (error: NSDictionary?) -> Void

var params :[String: AnyObject]? = ["user": "David", "age": 40]

func getTimeline(urlString: NSURL,params: [String: AnyObject], success successBlock :AlamoNetSuccess,
        failure failureBlock :AlamoNetFailure) {
.request(.GET, url, parameters: params, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("∙ ---")
                print("∙ Net URLs: \(response.request?.URL)")  // original URL request
                print("∙ ---")
                //print(response.response) // URL response
                //print(response.data)     // server data
                //print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    let jsonDic = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                    successBlock(result: jsonDic)
                } else {
                    let httpError: NSError = response.result.error!
                    let statusCode = httpError.code
                    let error:NSDictionary = ["error" : httpError,"statusCode" : statusCode]
                        failureBlock(error: error)
                }
}

let wrappedNetSuccess: AlamoNetSuccess = {(result: NSDictionary?) -> Void in // 
    print ("∙ Net Success: \(result)")
    // do whatever you want with your dictionary, parse it into datasource...
}

let wrappedAPIFailure: AlamoNetFailure = {(error: NSDictionary?) -> Void in
    print ("∙ Net Failure: \(error)")
    // handle your network error with alertViews or other..
}

apiManagerCurrentUserProfile.getTimeline(urlString,params:[], success: wrappedAPISuccess, failure: wrappedAPIFailure)
```